Failed to get service from broker. java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'
I am getting this error on google sign in and after every time my app starts.
Failed to get service from broker.  (Ask Gemini)
                 java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name com.google.android.gms'.
                    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Unknown Source:7)
                    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Unknown Source:0)
                    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Unknown Source:11)
                    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Unknown Source:10)
                    at anrz.a(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):36)
                    at anqg.z(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):143)
                    at amxn.run(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):54)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Unknown Source:2)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:4)
                    at btul.mA(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):1)
                    at btul.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):5)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Unknown Source:182)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:82)
                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(Unknown Source:28)
10:42:17.674  W  Failed to register com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller#com.google.android.gms (Ask Gemini)
                 elvi: 17: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
                    at elvk.a(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):13)
                    at ffdw.d(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):3)
                    at ffdy.run(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):130)
                    at fffr.execute(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):1)
                    at ffdz.h(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):1)
                    at ffdz.l(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):101)
                    at ffdz.p(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):19)
                    at edyc.hD(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):35)
                    at dtiv.run(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):14)
                    at fffr.execute(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):1)
                    at dtiw.b(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):18)
                    at dtjl.b(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):36)
                    at dtjn.c(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):26)
                    at amuv.c(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):9)
                    at amxl.q(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):48)
                    at amxl.d(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):10)
                    at amxl.g(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):211)
                    at amxl.onConnectionFailed(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):2)
                    at amxn.run(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):82)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Unknown Source:2)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:4)
                    at btul.mA(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):1)
                    at btul.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):5)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Unknown Source:182)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:82)
                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(Unknown Source:28)
                 Caused by: amtn: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
                    at anps.a(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):15)
                    at amuy.a(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):1)
                    at amuv.c(:com.google.android.gms@244631029@24.46.31 (190400-699197446):5)


I have integrated fire store, firebase messaging and google sign in using credential manager below is my related dependency versions in module build .grade
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.3.0'
 implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.3.0"
 implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials:1.3.0"
 implementation "com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid:1.1.1"
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.7.0')
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.2'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
 implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:4.1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:19.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.4'
 implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.0.3'
 implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.8.0'

and in project build .gradle
ext {
        agp_version = '8.6.1'
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    ext.compose_version = '1.5.0'
 dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.18.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

Also all these APIs are enabled in google cloud console

Token Service API
Identity Toolkit API
Firebase Installations API
Maps SDK for Android
Places API
Cloud Firestore API
Firebase Cloud Messaging API
Cloud Storage for Firebase API
Maps SDK for iOS
App Engine
App Engine Admin API
Artifact Registry API
BigQuery API
BigQuery Storage API
Cloud Build API
Cloud Datastore API
Cloud Deployment Manager V2 API
Cloud Functions API
Cloud Logging API
Cloud Messaging
Cloud Monitoring API
Cloud Pub/Sub API
Cloud Resource Manager API
Cloud Runtime Configuration API
Cloud SQL
Cloud Storage
Cloud Testing API
Cloud Trace API
Container Registry API
Directions API
Distance Matrix API
FCM Registration API
Firebase App Check API
Firebase App Distribution API
Firebase Dynamic Links API
Firebase Extensions API
Firebase Hosting API
Firebase In-App Messaging API
Firebase Management API
Firebase Remote Config API
Firebase Rules API
Geocoding API
Geolocation API
Gmail API
Google Cloud APIs
Google Cloud Storage JSON API
Legacy Cloud Source Repositories API
Maps Elevation API
Maps Embed API
Maps JavaScript API
Also added latest google-services file my app directory. Google sign-in works perfectly and all services like fire store etc. work no errors. Push notifications some times don't work. What's the possible resolution for this issue?
Right now the app does not crash on this error but it does show up in logcat. My app was already on google play console's bad behavior threshold. So I wanted to fix it as it could be contributing towards it or causing problems with push notifications. I have tried searching on stack overflow found similar issue here but could not find the solution. What could be missing?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
